# Why you need Metamask (and not to use a CDN or dependecy lib)?

Tags: contract-design, contract-invocation, contract-deployment, metamask, browsers

These days I'm asking myself why can't you inject web3 with dependency libraries or CDNs? Why yo need a browser plugin? I cannot understand it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The user needs to have a familiar environment to confirm transactions. This environment needs to be 100% shielded from the JavaScript on the website they are using. Otherwise, any website could perform Ethereum transactions without their consent, which would obviously be a disaster.

You don't necessarily need a browser plugin to have this. You can also just include the `web3.js` library yourself and connect to an Ethereum node running locally on the user's device:

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

When performing a transaction, the user will then be asked to confirm it inside their Ethereum client program.

Comment: But in that case, Metamask plugin should be accepted/configured for every webdapp?

Comment: @AlexAcc MetaMask is one of the most commonly used ways to use DApps. If you're writing a DApp it's a very good idea to support it.

Comment: Could you go deeper into how a hacker can perform a transaction without their consent? 

What do you mean include web3.js? in the front end? how does the user know to start up an Ethereum node?